# How to draw 3 rectangles with WebGL2

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader, webgl2

I am able to write out by hand the full boilerplate to WebGL2 pretty much, and have this much working.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
document.body.appendChild(canvas)

const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2', { antialias: true })
const width = 800
const height = 500

canvas.width = width
canvas.height = height

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)

gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, `#version 300 es

in vec3 position;
in vec4 color;

out vec4 thecolor;

void
main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);

  thecolor = color;
}
`)

gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in vec4 thecolor;

out vec4 color;

void
main() {
  color = thecolor;
}
`)

gl.compileShader(vertexShader)
var success = gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)
if (!success) throw new Error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader))

gl.compileShader(fragmentShader)
var success = gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)
if (!success) throw new Error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader))

const program = gl.createProgram()

gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)

gl.linkProgram(program)
gl.useProgram(program)

const positionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position')
const colorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'color')

gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height)
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

// I don't know what the purpose of this is.
const positionVAO = gl.createVertexArray()
gl.bindVertexArray(positionVAO)

const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer()

const vertexArray = [
  // don't know how to structure this on my own.
]

const indexArray = [
  // don't know how to structure this either.
]

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexArray), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indexArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW)

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorAttribute, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indexArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0)
```

However, there are 3 comments in there.

1. <del>I don't know what the purpose of `gl.createVertexArray` and `gl.bindVertexArray` are.</del> [This](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl1-to-webgl2.html) explains it.
2. Don't know how to structure the vertices in `vertexArray`.
3. Don't know how to structure the indices in `indexArray`.

I've gone through many tutorials but they usually gloss over the creation and definition of the the vertices/indices. They don't really explain how they designed them or structured them or why it's like that, so I haven't really been able to reconstruct it on my own yet. I would like to use `drawElements` with the indices instead of `drawArrays`.

Wondering if one could show how to draw 3 rectangles each with a different color (which gets passed in through the `vertexArray`). I was imagining interleaving the positions/colors in the `vertexArray`, but I don't know how to do that properly, and also don't know how to associate the data with the `indexArray`. By "properly", I mean I don't understand intuitively yet what goes into the `Float32Array` for vertices and the `Uint32Array` for indices. If it is `x, y`, or `x, y, r, g, b, a` in this case, or what. I don't understand how the rectangle closes and its "surface" gets colored. Wondering if one could help explain and demonstrate this drawing of 3 rectangles of different colors. That would help solidify how to draw in WebGL!

My attempt at drawing them is this:

```
const vertexArray = [
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // x y r g b a
  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
]

const indexArray = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4
]
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this is the are the last 2 parameters of [`gl.vertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#5.31).

The 5th parameter specifies the byte offset between the sets of consecutive generic vertex attributes. In your case each set of attributes consists of 6 values (x y r g b a) with type *float*. So the byte offset is 6*4 = 24.

The 6th parameter specifies the byte offset of the first component of the first generic vertex attribute in the array (In case when a named array buffer object is bound).
The offset for the vertex coordinates is 0, since this are the first 2 values.
The offset for the color attribute is 2*4 = 8, since the color attribute starts at the 3rd position.

So the specification of the vertex array has to be:

```js
const vertexArray = [
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // x y r g b a
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
]

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexArray), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 6*4, 0)

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorAttribute, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 6*4, 2*4)
```

You want to draw 2 triangles:

```
2           0    
  +--------+         0: (1, 1)
  |       /|         1: (0, 1)
  |    /   |         2: (1, 0)
  | /      |         3: (0, 0)
  + -------+
3           1
```

each triangle consists of 3 indices, so the array of indices has to be:

```js
const indexArray = [ 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1 ]

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indexArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

If you draw this using the [primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) type `TRIANGLES`,

```js
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indexArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0)
```

then this forms the 2 triangles with the coordinates:

```
1st : (1, 1) -> (1, 0) -> (0, 0)
2nd : (1, 1) -> (0, 0) -> (0, 1)
```

Of course it is possible to draw a triangles strip (`TRIANGLE_STRIP`) or triangle fan (`TRIANGLE_FAN`) instead:

```js
const indexArray = [ 2, 0, 3, 1 ]
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indexArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, indexArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0)
```

```js
const indexArray = [ 0, 2, 3, 1 ]
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indexArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, indexArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0)
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');

const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2', { antialias: true })
const width = 800
const height = 500

canvas.width = width
canvas.height = height

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)

gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, `#version 300 es

in vec3 position;
in vec4 color;

out vec4 thecolor;

void
main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);

  thecolor = color;
}
`)

gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in vec4 thecolor;

out vec4 color;

void
main() {
  color = thecolor;
}
`)

gl.compileShader(vertexShader)
var success = gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)
if (!success) throw new Error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader))

gl.compileShader(fragmentShader)
var success = gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)
if (!success) throw new Error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader))

const program = gl.createProgram()

gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)

gl.linkProgram(program)
gl.useProgram(program)

const positionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position')
const colorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'color')

gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height)
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

// I don't know what the purpose of this is.
const positionVAO = gl.createVertexArray()
gl.bindVertexArray(positionVAO)

const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer()

const vertexArray = [
   1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, // x y r g b a
   0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
   0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
]

const indexArray = [0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1]

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexArray), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indexArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW)

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 6*4, 0)

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorAttribute, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 6*4, 2*4)

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indexArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0)
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wondering if color should be 4*4 instead of 3*4, since rgba. It's not drawing for me still, but this seems close!

Comment: I still don't understand how, in `vertexArray` I just have `x` and `y`, but somehow the indices knows it's triangles? I don't get that.

Comment: @user10869858 `gl.TRIANGLES` in `gl.drawElements` indicates to form triangle primitives by 3 consecutive indies. I tried to point that out in the answer.